# Expose the functions of a .lib file

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, .lib

Is there is any way to Expose the functions(function names) inside a .lib file.

some thing like Dependency Walker to expose the function names in a DLL file.

Comment: With what purpose? If you're trying to develop against it you'll want the header file. Also, this isn't really a programming problem as you're asking for a software recommendation OR general programming questions not suited for stack overflow.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark exported functions / methods. Refer to this article for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx

Comment: Static libraries don't have "exported functions". `dllexport` is just for DLLs.  (The article mentions static libraries, but it is talking about a library which goes with a .dll, which the caller of the DLL can link to provide early binding -- this is nothing to do with what OP is asking)